# Write new bone constraint

Tags: python, rigging, add-on, constraints, source-code

I have an idea for an IK-like bone constraint solver which I'd like to try. As far as I understand, there is no way to add such a constraint via the python API, is this true? What is the simplest way to bring such a solver into Blender? Is the only way to add it to the source code and compile Blender from scratch, or is there a walk-around, if just for testing?

What needed to be possible for my idea to work is to:

- set a chain length
- recalculate the bone transforms for all bones in the chain from a given input transform (translation/rotation) as well as from the IDs of the selected and active bones